# Photoshop CC for Mac modifier keys inconsistent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I am having trouble with modifier keys such as holding shift to constrain, or command key to temporarily switch to Move Tool. Sometimes holding shift simply doesn't do anything. Sometimes it seems as if tapping shift once toggles on constraint mode. Also sometimes when using the brush tool I will press Command+Z to undo, and after releasing, the tool will remain in the Move tool instead of the brush tool, because normally when you HOLD command it will temporarily switch.
Is this a bug or is there something I am missing? Some key shortcut/click combo that is affecting their behaviors?
I have used Adobe products my entire life (Photoshop v3 when I was like 6 years old) and have never encountered this. I've been using CC 2015 just fine on PC, until now that I am trying on Mac and having these issues. Thanks for your help!
-Ben

Comment: You havn't accidentally enabled [sticky keys or slow keys](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18386?locale=en_US) have you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just checked and no, they are both turned off.

Comment: I use CC2015 at work on PC, and the way it's been behaving on Mac makes me feel it is incredibly buggy and unstable, but I'm surprised to not have found anything about this yet.

Comment: It happens to me sometimes on Photoshop CS6. I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: Here's a new one I just had. One of the modifier keys (not sure which one) somehow got toggled to always on, and when I tried to expand a group, all of them expanded, and when I clicked on other layers, they got added to the selection instead of becoming the newly selected layer.